# TypeError: $(...).dotdotdot is not a function?

Tags: jquery

A multipart question here, but I'll start with the main problem.

- I'm having issues getting a jQuery plugin to work on a site I'm designing.  FireBug is telling me that "TypeError: $(...).dotdotdot is not a function".  However, I've loaded the Jquery libraries in the correct order.  Does anyone know why my plugin is generating that error?
- Piggybacking off of that... I'm trying to use 'dotdotdot' to truncate metadata pulled from a Tumblr RSS feed.  Am I properly selecting that element in the script, or should I be pointing it at a different div/ID?  Currently it's looking for "#miniblog_d".

Thanks everyone for any assistance!  This one has been stumping me for a few weeks honestly.  If you review the file you'll notice I'm loading a king's ransom of jQuery libraries, and if there's a way to just load one, please let me know.  I haven't gotten any other scripts to work by just loading the latest jQuery file at the top.

Thank you!!

edit: I'm sorry - totally blanked here - live example is at http://tinychivalry.com/cjyoga/

Comment: Can you post your code so that we can see what you've tried doing already?

Comment: possible reasons...another library using `$` in page, jQuery in page is using `noConflict`, bad path to jQuery file, trying to use `$()` before loading jQuery....what other scripts are already in page? Also....should only load one version of jQuery in page, before all plugins and code that uses it

Comment: Hello All - thanks for the responses.  A live example is at http://tinychivalry.com/cjyoga/.  I updated my initial post as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're loading more than one version of jQuery on your page. You're actually doing it like this:

```
version X of jQuery
dotdotdot plugin
...
...
version Y of jQuery
...
...
```

What's happening is that the `dotdotdot` plugin is "attached" to the prototype of version X of jQuery, but then you load version Y, which overwrites version X, and makes everything attached to it no longer accessible, including your `dotdotdot` plugin.

Here's your header code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="custom_js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="custom_js/jquery.dotdotdot.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, print, projection"  href="sg_reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, print, projection"  href="drag_system.css" />
<!-- -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, print, projection"  href="cjyogaweb_common.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, print, projection"  href="cjyogaweb_common_textstyles.css" />
<!-- -->
<!--  -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="sg_jscripts/jquery_1.5.2_min.js"></script>
```

See how you're loading 1.9.1 and then 1.5.2 after it? That is your problem. Please only use a single version of jQuery, there are several reasons why it's ridiculous to do otherwise.

**EDIT** I just re-read your post and saw that you are indeed loading a crapload (technical term) of various versions of jQuery. This is, in no uncertain terms, wrong.

Comment: Thanks for this - I removed all references to 'jquery_1.5.2_min.js'.  - I also removed the lines that said  '<script type="text/javascript">var $ml = jQuery.noConflict();</script>', - I removed ANOTHER library I was loading, '<script type="text/javascript" src="custom_js/jquery.js"></script>'.  Removing the noConflict lines also breaks a separate script I'm using, but it seems to move things in the right direction.  I'll update this once I have some progress.  Thank you!!

Comment: one could also load **dotdotdot** via **$.get** call, then you don't have worries how many versions of jQuery is loaded [link](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)