# Rails and angular-dotdotdot: element.dotdotdot is not a function

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, bower

I am trying to include the [angular-dotdotdot directive](https://github.com/dunksmith/angular-dotdotot) in my angular app in my Rails project.

For this, I am using the [bower-rails gem](https://github.com/rharriso/bower-rails) to manage my assets, and in particular angular-dotdotdot. Hence I have the following files :

**bower.json**

```
{
  "lib": {
    "name": "bower-rails generated lib assets",
    "dependencies": {
    }
  },
  "vendor": {
    "name": "bower-rails generated vendor assets",
    "dependencies": {
      "angular-dotdotdot": "latest"
    }
  }
}
```

**.bowerrc**

```
{
  "directory" : "vendor/assets/bower_components"
}
```

**config/initializers/bower_rails.rb**

```
BowerRails.configure do |bower_rails|
  # Tell bower-rails what path should be considered as root. Defaults to Dir.pwd
  # bower_rails.root_path = Dir.pwd

  # Invokes rake bower:install before precompilation. Defaults to false
  # bower_rails.install_before_precompile = true

  # Invokes rake bower:resolve before precompilation. Defaults to false
  # bower_rails.resolve_before_precompile = true

  # Invokes rake bower:clean before precompilation. Defaults to false
  # bower_rails.clean_before_precompile = true

  # Invokes rake bower:install:deployment instead of rake bower:install. Defaults to false
  # bower_rails.use_bower_install_deployment = true
  #
  # Invokes rake bower:install and rake bower:install:deployment with -F (force) flag. Defaults to false
  # bower_rails.force_install = true

  # Change the default directory name
  # bower_rails.bower_components_directory = 'bower_components'

  asset "angular-dotdotdot"
end
```

In **vendor/assets/bower_components**, I have the angular-dotdotdot folder.

I am trying to include the directive following [the method indicated in the repo](https://github.com/dunksmith/angular-dotdotot/blob/master/js/angular-dotdotdot.js).

**app/assets/javascripts/bam-angular-app/modules/bam.js.coffee.erb**

```
@bamApp = angular
  .module('Bam.bamApp', [])
  .directive('dotdotdot', [
    '$timeout'
    ($timeout) ->
      {
        restrict: 'A'
        link: (scope, element, attributes) ->
          scope.$watch attributes.dotdotdot, ->
            $timeout (->
              console.log('before')
              element.dotdotdot()
              console.log('pass')
              return
            ), 400
            console.log('pass1')
            return
          console.log('pass2')
          return
      }
  ])
  .run(->
    console.log 'bamApp running'
  )
```

However, when I use it, I get the following error (twice, whereas I only use it once, if this is important) :

> Error: element.dotdotdot is not a function

Thanks to the log I included in my directive, I can see that I only pass once in the directive definition, and it stops at the `element.dotdotdot()` as it does output *before* but not *pass*.

Seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023948/typeerror-dotdotdot-is-not-a-function), I checked that I was not loading jQuery twice and I'm not. I am loading jquery, [jquery_ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) and [jquery.turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) once each.

I have no idea why I am getting this error.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you in advance!